# COUNT(DISTINCT X) MySQL Query doesn't give results I need

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, distinct

In MySQL I have a query to count all of the browsers from a page_views table that I want to aggregate. Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    Browser,
    COUNT(*)
FROM page_views
WHERE PageID = 58
GROUP BY Browser;
```

which gives, for example:

```
Chrome            14
Firefox           17
Internet Explorer 9
Opera             5
Safari            3
--------------------
Total             48
```

This is exactly what I want. It works fine and it's fast. Now I wanted to to a distinct on the IP address to remove users that have viewed the page more than once. I added `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT` so it looks like this:

```
SELECT
    Browser,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress)
FROM page_views
WHERE PageID = 58
GROUP BY Browser;
```

This looks like it works but in reality, I don't think it does. In my real-world environment, I do aggregates on multiple columns, one for Browser, on for day of the week, one for the month etc... so it's one query each but with different `GROUP BY`. How I noticed that it may not be the result I want is that every one of my queries has a different number for totals. Aggregating the views by browsers gives 48 total views, by day of week gives 45 total views, by month gives 50 total views. Something's not right.

Also, if I do a simple `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress) FROM page_views WHERE PageID = 58` I get much less page views that the other aggregate queries have as a total.

Again, what I want is the first query I put above but only aggregate once for each IPAddress so it basically calculates the unique viewers of a page and not the total of views a page has.

What am I doing, or not doing correctly to get the results I want?

Thank you.

Comment: Does `IPAddress` contain NULL values?

Comment: It means that same user visit the page with different browsers, is this a problem?

Comment: Is a new record inserted for every pageview? If only one user views pageID 58, 10 times, once every hour then `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress)` will be `1` but `SELECT Browser, COUNT(*)` will be `10`. Isn't that compatible with what you have mentioned?

Comment: @Scorpi0 Maybe this is why I get different results. So, I'm guessing the query says "I got a user that viewed the page with Safari and also with Chrome? Which one do you want? I might as well include the 2." Is that right?

Comment: @AzizShaikh Yes, that is the behaviour I want.

Comment: With whatever queries and data you have provided in your question, I think you are getting correct results. Please explain what results you want to see, so that help can be provided to you.

Comment: Basically, I want to get all the distinct users (IP addresses), let's say I have 30 unique users for my views of page 58 and I want to start aggregating them on the browser, month of page viewed etc. I think I understand now where the issue is. A user can view a page multiple times so which record will it use for the distinct(?).

Comment: I think I just answered by own question. I see now where the problem lies. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
SELECT
    Browser,
    day_of_the_week,
    month_of_the_year,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress)
FROM page_views
WHERE PageID = 58
GROUP BY Browser, day_of_the_week,month_of_the_year
```

The total of `count(distinct)` will no be the same as in your simple query.

If you want to eliminate duplicate IP-adresses in the same day, you'll need something like this:

```
SELECT 
  p1.Browser
  , p1.pageID
  , p1.WEEKDAY(`date`) as day_of_week
  , p1.MONTH(`date`) as The_month
  , COUNT(p2.Unique_visitors_this_day) as uniqueviews
FROM page_views p1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, 1 as Unique_visitors_this_day FROM page_views pv1
           LEFT JOIN page_views pv2 ON (pv1.id > pv2.id 
                                     AND pv1.ipaddress = pv2.ipaddress
                                     AND pv1.`date` = pv2.`date`)
           WHERE pv2.id IS NULL) as p2
       ON (p1.id = p2.id)
 WHERE p1.PageID = 58
 GROUP BY p1.Browser, p1.day_of_week, p1.The_month;
```